# Angular 8 compile Issue

Tags: angular8, angular-compiler-cli

I have a problem compiling my Angular 8 application:

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 11.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 12.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 2.64 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-07-28T21:19:53.546Z - Hash: 770b00fb42b4664247d8 - Time: 10789ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
    
Date: 2020-07-28T21:21:23.611Z - Hash: 0c9595fa24b10bb14e7a
4 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 11.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 73459ms
: Compiled successfully.
92% additional asset processing copy-webpack-plugin
```

When the project is being compiled, it will stuck at that last line reporting 92% of additional asset processing by `copy-webpack-plugin`.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try deleting your node_modules and run npm install again.

Comment: I did this one. But not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try to stop ng serve and try it once again?